# Jenkins MultiBranch Pipeline: Select to build only 2 specific branches

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins MultiBranch project and I want the test circle to run only on two specific branches on `master` and on `dev`. I tried to add on all stages the following

```
when { anyOf { branch 'master'; branch 'dev' } }
```

but the only thing I managed to achieve was to deactivate all branch runs

Here is my full pipeline Jenkinsfile

```
    pipeline {
        agent any
        triggers {
            cron('H 0 * * *')
        }
        options {
            disableConcurrentBuilds()
        }
        stages {
        stage('Prepare env') {
            when { anyOf { branch 'master'; branch 'dev' } }
            steps {
               sh 'rm -rf venv'
               sh 'rm -rf "${WORKSPACE}/uploads"'
               sh 'rm -rf "${WORKSPACE}/downloads"'
               sh 'mkdir "${WORKSPACE}/uploads"'
               sh 'mkdir "${WORKSPACE}/downloads"'
               catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE')
               {
                     sh 'docker kill $(docker ps -q)'
                     sh 'docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)'
             sh 'docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)'
               }
    
            }
        }
        
            stage('Start Services') {
            when { anyOf { branch 'master'; branch 'dev' } }
                steps {
           
                }
            }
    
            stage('Test Common') {
            when { anyOf { branch 'master'; branch 'dev' } }
                steps {
    
                }
            }
    
        stage('Test Validations') {
            when { anyOf { branch 'master'; branch 'dev' } }
                steps {
    
                }
            }
    
            stage('Test CSV Issuance') {
            when { anyOf { branch 'master'; branch 'dev' } }
                steps {
    
                }
            }
     
        
            stage('Test XLS Issuance') {
            when { anyOf { branch 'master'; branch 'dev' } }
                steps {
    
                }
            }
     
    
        
            stage('Clean env') {
            when { anyOf { branch 'master'; branch 'dev' } }
                steps {
                   sh 'rm -rf venv'
                   sh 'rm -rf "${WORKSPACE}/uploads"'
                   sh 'rm -rf "${WORKSPACE}/downloads"'
                   catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE')
                   {
                      sh 'docker kill $(docker ps -q)'
                      sh 'docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)'
                      sh 'docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)'
                   }
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you post the full pipeline you have?

You would use the `when` block on the stage you want run only on the two branches e.g.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages
    {
        stage ("Testing") {
            when {
                anyOf {
                    branch 'master'
                    branch 'dev'
                }
            }
            steps {
                echo "run testing"
            }
        }
        stage ("everything") {
            steps{
                echo "run on all branches"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

tested pipeline

```
pipeline { 
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("stage") {
            when { anyOf { branch 'master'; branch 'dev' } }
            steps {
                echo "Hello"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

on master

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (stage)
[Pipeline] echo
Hello
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```

On Fish

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (stage)
Stage "stage" skipped due to when conditional
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```

Comment: I added almost full of the file!

Comment: OK so you have the when clause on every stage therefore there are no stages to run on branches that are not `master` or `dev`.  What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: the problem is that `master` or `dev` branche are not running either!

Comment: Thats strange, can you post some of you console log.  I have just tested with a simple pipeline (see above) and it is working.  So be interesting to see why it is skipping in your case

Comment: Is there any other way through multibranch project configuration to set these two branches as the only to activate a run?

Comment: Yes,you can do a regex in Jenkins to set the branches to run, Click the add button at the bottom and then select the one that says regex.